# How to make " untargetable" a choice with a boolean?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an RPG game for school with 2 players, both players will choose 3 characters to fight ! and when one of the characters run out of health points... he dies !

And actually I'm trying to figure out how can I do this I already make the function death, here it is :

```
 public func death(to attacker: Character, of target: Character, from ennemyPlayer: Player){
    if healthpoint <= 0 {
        isDead = true
        print("\(target.name) is KO")
    }
}
```

but I don't know where to put my function to make untargetable a choice like if one player pick a character with 0hp it says print("This char is dead")

I made this function to choose a char ( this function is not one the same folder as the death function) :

```
 //function to choose a fighter
func chooseChar(charac: inout[Character]){

    var attacker: Character
    var inputRole: Bool = false

    repeat{
        let choice = readLine()
        switch choice {
        case "1":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[0]
            charac.append(attacker)
            inputRole = true
        case "2":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[1]
            charac.append(attacker)
            inputRole = true
        case "3":
            attacker = self.playerTeam[2]
            charac.append(attacker)
            inputRole = true
        default:
            print("choose between 1, 2 or 3")
            inputRole = false
        }
    } while inputRole == false
}
```

Thanks a lot for help ! have a nice day

Comment: Your `Character` should have an `isDead` property (which would probably be a computed property based on hp <= 0). Then, when a character is selected you can check its `isDead` property. Also I don't see a good reason to use an `inout` parameter in `chooseChar`; it should just return the chosen character.

Comment: You can also simplify that `switch` statement. Convert the input string to an `Int` (the conversion can fail, so you need to use `if let...` verify it is >0 and <4 and then you can just index the array by subtracting 1.  If you use `charac.count` for your bounds check then your code can adapt to any number of characters in the array.

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for the reply, I already did in character the isDead property but I don't know why I can't recall it in my function chooseChar...

Answer (score 1):

You can add `isDead` as a computed property to your `Character` class:

```
class Character {
    var hp: Int
    var isDead: Bool {
        return hp < 1
    }
}
```

You can make your `chooseChar` function more flexible by adapting to the array size. This function should also return the selected character rather than using an `inout` array:

```
func chooseChar(characters: [Character]) -> Character {

    var attacker: Character?

    repeat{
        let line = readLine()
        if let choice = Int(line), 
           choice > 0, 
           choice <= characters.count {
               let selection = characters[choice-1]
               if selection.isDead {
                   print("\(selection.name) is already dead!")
               } else {
                   attacker = selection
               }
        } else {
            print("Please enter a number between 1 and \(characters.count)"
        }
    } while attacker == nil
    return attacker
}
```

Comment: Ok Paul I used your code but I got an error at the line characters.count ( I have no member count) and at the line characters[choice-1] (type character has no subscript members) tried to figure out but nothing ...

Comment: Check your code. It sounds like you haven't declared the parameter `characters` as an array

Comment: Thanks Paul you were right I forgot to declare the parameter characters as an array, but still when I want to use my function chooseChar() I don't know what to put in parameter...

Comment: Your array of possible target characters is that the player can choose who they are fighting. I can't be more specific because I don't know how you have structured your program